# Running loadjava with Windows authentication

Tags: oracle, windows, authentication

I want to run following command under Windows with Oracle Database 12c installed:

`loadjava -force -genmissing -r -user username/password@database -verbose core-1.7.jar`

The problem is that I use Windows authentication and I connect the following way:

`sqlplus / as sysdba`

and I do not enter any username or password. Could you please tell me how to execute first command under Windows for a pluggable database?

Comment: `core-1.7.jar` ??? I hope you are not trying to upgrade/downgrade the JVM that is inside the DB.  Also,  have you tried using SQL*Developer to load the `jar`?

Comment: I am following this guide https://community.oracle.com/message/13360407#13360407 so as to be able to generate QR codes on demand. I didn't know I can. Will look that online.

Comment: Connecting the way you do is strictly only exclusively for DBA tasks (like starting up and shutting down your database. You **never** **ever** use that to connect to the database for any other use - specifically **not** for running or developing applications. You **always** connect as a specific user.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use SYS for this.

With a regular user, you can simply provide the `username/password@address`.

To do this with SYS, without the password:

Create the class:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>copy con Hello.java
public class Hello
{
    public static String world()
    {
    return "Hello World";
    }
}
^Z
        1 file(s) copied.

C:\Users\Administrator>type Hello.java
public class Hello
{
    public static String world()
    {
    return "Hello World";
    }
}

C:\Users\Administrator>set JAVA_HOME=O:\oracle\base\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\jdk

C:\Users\Administrator>set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

C:\Users\Administrator>javac Hello.java

C:\Users\Administrator>jar cvf Hello.jar Hello.class
added manifest
adding: Hello.class(in = 273) (out= 209)(deflated 23%)
```

Connect to pluggable database without password:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Fri Nov 9 16:18:34 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;

Session altered.
```

Load the class:

```
SQL> exec dbms_java.loadjava('C:\Users\Administrator\Hello.jar');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select owner, object_name, object_type, status, created
     from dba_objects where object_name = 'Hello';

OWNER      OBJECT_NAM OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS  CREATED
---------- ---------- ----------------------- ------- ---------
SYS        Hello      JAVA CLASS              INVALID 09-NOV-18

SQL> alter java class "Hello" compile;

Java altered.

SQL> select owner, object_name, object_type, status, created
     from dba_objects where object_name = 'Hello';

OWNER      OBJECT_NAM OBJECT_TYPE             STATUS  CREATED
---------- ---------- ----------------------- ------- ---------
SYS        Hello      JAVA CLASS              VALID   09-NOV-18
```

Clean up the mess:

```
SQL> drop java class "Hello";

Java dropped.
```